# Rails log show redirect but view remain same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using rails 3.2.21. I want to redirect a request after creating new element on specific condition. 
my controller create action code :

```
def create
@community_group = Community::Group.new(params[:community_group])
@community_group.member_ids = []
@community_group.member_ids = params[:member_ids].present? ?  [@current_user.id] + params[:member_ids] :  [@current_user.id]

respond_to do |format|
  if @community_group.save
    format.html{ redirect_to community_group_path(@community_group) }
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Group Saving Failed'
    format.html{}
  end

end
```

end

N.B: I did not use 
    **remote: true** 
for form submission.

I see on log that it redirect request to right path and render right page. I check using Rails.logger.info where is my expected page rendered or not and it seems to me ok.
My log info for create action:

```
Started POST "/community/groups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-03 14:18:47 +0600
Processing by Community::GroupsController#create as HTML
```

and then successfully  redirect to show action (my log info)

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3001/community/groups/53
Completed 302 Found in 1008.4ms (ActiveRecord: 208.7ms)
```

Now new request start: (my log info)

```
Started GET "/community/groups/53" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-03 17:08:52 +0600
Processing by Community::GroupsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"53"}
```

but my view remains on same page with same url. I don't understand this problem. Please help if any one face same type of problem.

My show action code:

```
def show
@community_group = Community::Group.find(params[:id])
@community_group_post = @community_group.community_group_posts.order("id DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
respond_to do |format|
format.html 
end
```

end

Comment: What activity performs the 'new request start'?

Comment: Can you share controller action that gets executed on this URL? http://localhost:3001/community/groups/53

Comment: I add my show action code. Please see now @Dabrorius

Comment: do you have any `:before_action` (or `:before_filter`) in this controller? Because something is redirecting from `show` (`GET /community/groups/53`) to `index` (`GET "/community/groups"`).

Comment: Hi @basia , it was my mistake. I Mistakenly past other log. Now i update my post and thanks to notify me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was not controller level problem or request redirect related problem(request redirect according to code). My problem was, i use iframe as my form target. So, request redirect to target iframe and refresh it but i was expecting full page refresh. I use JavaScript forcefully refresh full page to solve my problem.

```
window.location.reload();
```

[534 other ways to reload the page with JavaScript](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html).

For newbie web developer like me, i want to add extra information about html form target attribute.

Target is used to specify in which window you would like to show the response from the server upon submitting your form.

Possible values are :

- _blank - new page
- frame - show in the iframe with the given name
- _self - show in the same iframe where the form locates
- _parent - show in the parent page/iframe of the form's iframe
- _top - the top most window

I think above information may be valuable to someone.